# background-position-x + animate Right to Left +IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Animate issue in IE.
I am trying to move background left and right continually and smoothly.  the code is working fine for all browser excluding IE. 
**Issue**: while moving Left to Right showing the problem.
 Please find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/uy9pcvkj/3/)  which I have added.

```js
function call1(){
 $('.container').animate({ 'background-position-x': '100%' }, 2000);
}

function animateBg(){
    call1();
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('.container').animate({ 'background-position-x': '0%' }, 2000,function(){
   animateBg();
        });
        console.log("hii");
    });
}

animateBg();
```

```css
.main{height:100%;}
.container{
    background:url('http://www.smartbygep.com/sites/default/files/SBG-home-page-banner.jpg')no-repeat top center;
    background-position-x:0%;   
    color:#333; /*-moz-transition: all .5s;
     -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);*/
    background-size:120% 100%;             
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        Sample text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AleshaOleg reproducible in all the versions of IE (IE8-11)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
animate({ backgroundPosition: '0%' }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uy9pcvkj/25/)